# Why does character <S in Excel file screwed up PHPExcel to read data?

Tags: php, arrays, excel, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using PHPExcel in my Yii2 App. In my Excel file, there's a cell that contain  data like this [image]

Then I try to printout in screen using **print_r** and then I got array result like this [image]. It should be `Array ( [0] => 52034563 [1] => Chemical Books<S [2] => EAS [3] => A1 [4] => [5] => 00000_S [6]`
But, in the result the Index [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZhSc.png) is missing, and the `Chemical Book<s` become `Chemical Books`, and then all the array got Black Line.

But when I remove the `<S`, the array result has complete index and doesn't has Black Line.

**Why does it happen, and How do I can make the PHPExcel can read the Excel data well even the data contain `<S` ?**

Comment: Html `s` tag (which is `<s`) stands for `strikethrough`.

Comment: Yah, that's right @u_mulder, I've set ></s in next cell, and the strikethrough end before it. Thanks.